# algebraic expression of Matrix product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $M = X^T \Delta X$, where $X$ and $\Delta$ are $P \times P$ matrices and $\Delta$ is symmetric.

Can anyone give a simple algebraic expression of the matrix $M$?

Comment: Isn't $M=X^T \Delta X$ already just that? What more do you want?

Comment: I meant in the form of \sum

Comment: So, for example
$$m_{i,j}=\sum_{k=1}^{P}\sum_{p=1}^{P}x_{k,i}\delta_{k,p}x_{p,j}$$
is the entry-wise expression for that matrix multiplication. But I assume that's not what you'd like?

Comment: Thanks. This is what I wanted, indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the matrix multiplication can be expressed entry-wise as

$$m_{i,j}=\sum_{k=1}^P\sum_{p=1}^Px_{k,i}\delta_{k,p} x_{p,j}.$$